# PHP xpath - find element with a value and also get elements before and after element

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Lets say I have this XML:

```
<images>
    <photo>
        <thumbImg>images/thumbs/002.jpg</thumbImg>
        <filename>002</filename>
    </photo>
    <photo>
        <thumbImg>images/thumbs/008.jpg</thumbImg>
        <filename>008</filename>
    </photo>
    <photo>
        <thumbImg>images/thumbs/003.jpg</thumbImg>
        <filename>003</filename>
    </photo>
    <photo>
        <thumbImg>images/thumbs/006.jpg</thumbImg>
        <filename>006</filename>
    </photo>
    <photo>
        <thumbImg>images/thumbs/005.jpg</thumbImg>
        <filename>005</filename>
    </photo>
</images>
```

And I want to find the  element with the filename value of 003 and then find the  elements 1 prior and 1 after that element. This is all so I can get the data for a prev/next functionality as well as show the selected image on a page. I was thinking this would do it:

```
$image_id = "003";
$project = $xml_object->xpath("photo[filename='$image_id']");
```

But it print_r's an empty array... Is there an easy way with xpath to do this perhaps? I figured that I could do it by just looping through and putting the prev/next elements into a temp array, then once it's found, break the loop and return the temp data, but I thought xpath might be able to do it a little more elegantly.

EDIT: solved - here's the clearer answer for the sibling nodes:

```
// for the one prior
//photo[filename='$image_id']/preceding-sibling::photo[1]
// for the one after
//photo[filename='$image_id']/following-sibling::photo[1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$project = $xml_object->xpath("//photo[filename='$image_id']");
```

Comment: awesome, that works - how would you get the previous and next elements too?

Comment: `$project = $xml_object->xpath("//photo");
while(list( , $node) = each($project)) {
  var_dump($node);
 }` would iterate over the entire loop.

Comment: sorry, to clarify - how would I go about getting the single element prior and the single element directly after, not all of the photo elements

Comment: nevermind - got it - //photo[filename='$image_id']/preceding-sibling::photo[1] for the previous, //photo[filename='$image_id']/following-sibling::photo[1] for the one after

Comment: Nice. Will have to remember that.