# parse simplexml based on child value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP xpath - find element with a value and also get elements before and after element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279544/php-xpath-find-element-with-a-value-and-also-get-elements-before-and-after-ele)

I have the following xml:

```
<Table>
    <ID>100</ID>
    <Name>Fridge</Name>
    <Description>A cool refrigerator</Description>
</Table>
<Table>
    <ID>100</ID>
    <Name>Fridge</Name>
    <Description>Latest Refrigerator</Description>
</Table>
<Table>
    <ID>200</ID>
    <Name>Fridge</Name>
    <Description>Another refrigerator</Description>
</Table>
```

In the example above, I would like to get the child values of Name and Description for the nodes with ID=100. There are around 1000 Table nodes in the xml file.

How can i parse the entire xml and get the Name and Description values for only the nodes with ID equal to 100 ?

So far, i have tried the following code, which could not give what i wanted:

```
$source = 'Tables.xml';
$xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
$sitemap = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$sitemap = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);

foreach($sitemap as $url) {

    if($url->ID == '100')
    {
        echo 'Name: '.(string)$url->Name.', Description: '.(string)$url->Description.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that there is plenty of q&a about XPath and traversing XML on SO, I have to ask: what have you tried?

Comment: @Gordon I have tried the above code in my edited question

Comment: well, you can see in my codepad example that it works. I cant tell you whats wrong with your code because I dont know your XML. In any case, the XML snippet you show is invalid without a root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward if you get all `Table` tags and loop over them:

```
// Assuming you already loaded the XML into the SimpleXML object $xml
$names_and_descriptions = array();
foreach ($xml->Table as $t) {
  if ($t->ID == 100) {
    echo $t->Name . " " . $t->Description . "\n";
    // Or stick them into an array or whatever...
    $names_and_descriptions[] = array(
      'name'=>$t->Name, 
      'description'=>$t->Description
    );
  }
}
var_dump($names_and_descriptions);
```